# How to Add Awesome Alert in Functional Component

Tags: react-native, alert, react-functional-component

I'm using [Awesome Alert](https://github.com/rishabhbhatia/react-native-awesome-alerts) for customize alert but I would like to apply it in functional component environment. This is my design

[image: Alert Design]

And this is my code

```
<AwesomeAlert
            show={true}
            showProgress={false}
            title="AwesomeAlert"
            message="I have a message for you!"
            closeOnTouchOutside={false}
            closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
            showCancelButton={true}
            showConfirmButton={true}
            cancelText="Reject"
            confirmText="Approve"
            confirmButtonColor="#AEDEF4"
            cancelButtonColor="#DD6B55"
            onCancelPressed={() => {
              console.log("Reject")
            }}
            onConfirmPressed={() => {
              console.log("Approve")
            }}
          />
```

My question is, is Awesome Alert can only be applied in Class component? How am I able to implement it in Functional Component like the original Alert React Native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AwesomeAlert` inside a functional component as you would inside a class component's `render()` function; any React component that can be rendered from a class component can also be rendered from a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside your `return` part of your functional component and it will work

For Example like this:

```js
return (
    <View>
        <AwesomeAlert
            show={true}
            showProgress={false}
            title="AwesomeAlert"
            message="I have a message for you!"
            closeOnTouchOutside={false}
            closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
            showCancelButton={true}
            showConfirmButton={true}
            cancelText="Reject"
            confirmText="Approve"
            confirmButtonColor="#AEDEF4"
            cancelButtonColor="#DD6B55"
            onCancelPressed={() => {
              console.log("Reject")
            }}
            onConfirmPressed={() => {
              console.log("Approve")
            }}
          />
    </View>
)
```